# Need help to update a sql table from excel sheet using vb script

Tags: mysql, excel, vbscript

Thank you in advance.
My aim is to update sql table from excel. So i wrote a vbscript to  get sql table from my-sql to excel on a single click. Table looks like this:-

```
id  rule    length  isactive    date
1   rule 1     3       1        NULL
2   rule 2     5       0        NULL
3   rule 3     6       1        NULL
4   rule 4     7       1        8/10/2015
5   rule 5     3       0        NULL
```

Now i will update `length`, `isactive`, `date` fields and this data should be updated in the table on a single click. Please help me in this script. I tried update query which is failing with run time error-

> 80040e14.

part of script is

```
For iCount = 2 To 6
intRLength = CInt(objSheet.Cells(iCount, 3).Value)
intID = CInt(objSheet.Cells(iCount, 1).Value)
strQuerie = "UPDATE" & strDatabase & "." & strTable & "SET retentionlength=" & intRLenth & "where id= " & intID

rs.Open strQuerie   ' --- Getting run time error- 80040e14 message here
Next
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's most probably because of spacing issue in some part of your formed query

Your query should rather look like

```
strQuerie = "UPDATE " & strDatabase & "." & strTable & " SET retentionlength=" & intRLenth & " where id= " & intID
```

Otherwise, as it stands; your query would look like below which clearly way wrong

```
UPDATEDB_NAME.TABLE_NAMESET retentionlength=somevaluewhere id= someid
```

Comment: I am still getting Runtime error -2147217900(80040e14), after update

Comment: Echo your `strQuerie` and see how it looks.

Comment: Thankyou Rahul. It worked. I gave wrong variable name- intRLenth instead of intRlength.

Comment: @Lakshmi, make sure you are providing correct values then it should work. Consider posting a separate question if there is a different question you have. Also, consider accepting the answer if it helped by clicking the check button.

Comment: But I'm failing to update Date field in a similar way..
date in excel is- 8/6/2014

 idate = CDate(objSheet.Cells(iCount, 5).Value) 

strQuerie2 = "UPDATE " & strDatabase & "." & strTable & " SET lastrunDate=" & idate & " where id= " & intID  

date considered is 12/29/1899.  what modification should be done?

Comment: @Lakshmi, you need to quote the date value like `" SET lastrunDate= '" & idate & "' where id= "`